# Are directional derivatives of $f(x,y,z) = \sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}}$ at origin are same in every direction.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Are directional derivatives of $f(x,y,z) = \sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}}$ at origin are same in every direction.
(True or false)
I know how to find directional derivative in the direction of a given vector.

Gradient for the given vector is

Grad$(f) = (xi + yj + zk)/\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}}$

Now how can I find it at origin$?$

Moreover what should be concluded about all other directional derivatives and their directions$?$

Comment: By spherical symmetry, it is obvious that if the derivative exists in some direction, it will be the same in all. Hence it is enough to consider, say, $\partial f/\partial x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The direction derivatives at the origin do not exist. If $v=(a,b,c)\neq(0,0,0)$, then the directional derivative at the origin of $f$ with respect to the direction given by $v$ is$$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(ta,tv,tc)-f(0,0,0)}t=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\lvert t\rvert}t\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$$and, since $\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\neq0$, this limit doesn't exist.